# canvas scale only size but not coordinates

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am trying to animate a canvas element with scale. Is it possible t**o only scale the size(width&height) of an element without scaling the coordinates system?** The standard ctx.scale(x,y) seem to be affecting both.

If your run this code snippet, you will see that the element is becoming larger. However, it's also moving from one position to another.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("c");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var cH; 
var cW;
cW = window.innerWidth;
cH = window.innerHeight;
c.width = cW * devicePixelRatio;
c.height = cH * devicePixelRatio;
ctx.scale(devicePixelRatio, devicePixelRatio);
var startX = 200;
var startY = 100;
var currentScale = 0.1

function animateCloud () {
  // draw cloud shape
  ctx.scale(currentScale, currentScale)
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(startX, startY);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(startX - 40, startY + 10, startX - 20, startY + 180, startX + 60, startY + 70);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(startX + 100, startY + 100, startX + 150, startY + 100, startX + 150, startY + 70);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(startX + 280, startY + 70, startX + 230, startY + 40, startX + 210, startY + 20);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(startX + 360, startY - 40, startX + 210, startY - 50, startX + 160, startY - 30);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(startX + 150, startY - 75, startX + 80, startY - 60, startX + 70, startY - 30);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(startX + 30, startY - 75, startX - 10, startY - 60, startX, startY);
  ctx.closePath();

  ctx.lineWidth = 5;
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#333";
  ctx.stroke();
  
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0)

  if (currentScale >= 1 ){
    
  }else{
    currentScale += 0.1
    console.log(currentScale)
    console.log('animations going')
    requestAnimationFrame(animateCloud)
  }
}

requestAnimationFrame(animateCloud)
```

```css
canvas {
  display: block;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  cursor: pointer; 
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

I want it to stay on the same position but grows larger. The scaling is affect the coordinates too that's why it's moving in terms of positions.

One solution I could think of is to go through each path's coordinates and divide it by the scale variable. However intuitively that just seems like an awful solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the position of where things scale from using `translate` (and `rotate` and `scale`). Things always scale around the origin. The origin starts at 0,0 the upper left corner. If you want to scale from somewhere else you need to move that origin then draw stuff around that origin.

Example:

```js
const ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");

function render(time) {
  time *= 0.001; // seconds
  
  const width = ctx.canvas.width;
  const height = ctx.canvas.height;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  
  // save all the canvas settings
  ctx.save();
  
  // move origin to center of canvas
  ctx.translate(width / 2, height / 2);
  
  const xScale = lerp(.5, 2, sinLerp(time * 1.1));
  const yScale = lerp(.5, 2, sinLerp(time * 1.7));
  
  ctx.scale(xScale, yScale);
  
  // draw a rectangle around the origin
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.fillRect(-20, -10, 40, 20);
  
  // restore all the canvas settings
  ctx.restore();
  
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);

// returns a number between 0 and 1
function sinLerp(t) {
  return Math.sin(t) * .5 + .5;
}

// returns a number bewteen a and b
// assuming t is between 0 and 1 inclusive
function lerp(a, b, t) {
  return a + (b - a) * t;
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

In your case first move the origin to where you want the center of your shape, then scale, then move the origin from its current position so that when you draw your shape its center will be at the origin. In your case your cloud appears to be 600x200 large so in order to make the center of that get drawn at the origin (0,0) we need translate -300,-100

```js
var c = document.getElementById("c");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var cH; 
var cW;
cW = window.innerWidth;
cH = window.innerHeight;
c.width = cW * devicePixelRatio;
c.height = cH * devicePixelRatio;
ctx.scale(devicePixelRatio, devicePixelRatio);
var startX = 200;
var startY = 100;
var currentScale = 0.1

function animateCloud () {
  // draw cloud shape

  // move the origin to the center (or anywhere)
  ctx.translate(c.width / 2, c.height / 2);
  
  ctx.scale(currentScale, currentScale);
  
  // move the origin from the center
  // so that the center is in the
  // center of your cloud
  
  // PS: just guessed the center is at 300,100
  // so you need to start drawing at -300,-100
  // from the origin so your shape's center
  // ends up at 0,0
  ctx.translate(-300, -100);
  
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(startX, startY);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(startX - 40, startY + 10, startX - 20, startY + 180, startX + 60, startY + 70);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(startX + 100, startY + 100, startX + 150, startY + 100, startX + 150, startY + 70);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(startX + 280, startY + 70, startX + 230, startY + 40, startX + 210, startY + 20);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(startX + 360, startY - 40, startX + 210, startY - 50, startX + 160, startY - 30);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(startX + 150, startY - 75, startX + 80, startY - 60, startX + 70, startY - 30);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(startX + 30, startY - 75, startX - 10, startY - 60, startX, startY);
  ctx.closePath();

  ctx.lineWidth = 5;
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#333";
  ctx.stroke();
  
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0)

  if (currentScale >= 1 ){
    
  }else{
    currentScale += 0.1
    console.log(currentScale)
    console.log('animations going')
    requestAnimationFrame(animateCloud)
  }
}

requestAnimationFrame(animateCloud)
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
canvas {
  display: block;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  cursor: pointer; 
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```